# NextJS App Directory | How to pass middleware data into a page.tsx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here are the repos associated with this question.

Client - https://github.com/Phillip-England/plank-steady

Server - https://github.com/Phillip-England/squid-tank

First off, thank you for your time. I appreciate it. Here is what I am trying to do. Keep in mind, I am using Next js with the new App directory features.

Basically, I have my user in json format in my middleware function, and I want to pipe this data into the following page.tsx route being rendered.

I've read the docs 10 times over and I get the feeling I don't quite understand the underlying mechanics of next js. Really just trying to understand how data flows from these server components into the actual use and how to pass data around between server components and middleware.

Okay, so my middleware is all routed up and I am getting my user from my API. I actually have the user JSON in my middleware function. Here is the middleware function.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { getUser } from "./lib/getUser";
import { cookies } from "next/dist/client/components/headers";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

// middleware for /cfa
  const sessionToken = request.cookies.get('session-token')
  if (sessionToken == undefined) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
  }
  const userRequest = await getUser(sessionToken.value)
  if (userRequest.status != 200) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
  }
  const userJson = await userRequest.json()
}


export const config = {
    matcher: "/cfa",
}
```

So, at the very end, the user json is valid and contains the correct data. It has the fields of _id and email.

Okay, so lets say we hit /cfa (which serves as the basic user level protected branch of my url endpoints)

I want this user json to be available for use in my page.

Here is an exmaple of a page which would need this user data.

```
import { FormCreateLocation } from "@/components/forms/FormCreateLocation";
import { Location } from "@/components/resources/Location";
import { getUser } from "@/lib/getUser";
import { cookies, headers } from "next/dist/client/components/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function Home() {

  return (
    <main className="">
      <FormCreateLocation />
      <div className="p-4">
        <h2>Select a Location</h2>
        <ul>
          {/* mock location */}
          <Location _id="0333333333" name="Chick-fil-A Highway 22" number="03444" />
          <Location _id="33222222222" name="Chick-fil-A Midtown" number="03253" />
        </ul>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. I deeply appreciate the time, thank you.

I've tried setting the user as a cookie in my middleware and then retrieving the cookie in my actual page.

I've tried setting the user data as a x-user header and then trying to access it in the page.

I've tried mounting the user data to the actually NextRequest and then unpack it in the actual page.

I've tried simply returning the user data to see if it would be available in the endpoint.

I've also read the docs multiple times and spend a good solid few hours on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you have to set a custom header (or cookie) from your middleware, and then you can access it on you page.tsx file. And this is what you have already tried. But, at the very end of your middleware function, you have to return your NextRequest, with the new headers set. Here is an example

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {

    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    // add field to request headers
    requestHeaders.set("X-My-Custom-Header", "CustomHeaderValue");
    return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    });

}
```

And, in your `page.tsx` file you can access your headers using the `headers` function provided by Next.JS

```
export default async function Posts() {
    const head = headers();
    console.log(head);
    return (<> Your Page </>)
}
```

And in the console the output will be

```
...allPreSetHeaders
x-my-custom-header: CustomHeaderValue
```

(the key is lower case, because headers are case-insensitive)